# communication between containers does not work in docker network

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-network

I'm trying to connect two containers(spring boot app and mongo db) through docker network.

I created the docker network:

```
docker network create springmongo
```

Then, I create the docker db container:

```
docker run --network=springmongo --name=mongocontainer mongo
```

Then, I created the spring boot app contianer:

```
docker run --network=springmongo --name=mongo-client-api mongo-client-api
```

`docker ps` command show this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
213526cf2bd4        mongo-client-api       "/bin/sh -c 'exec ja…"   31 seconds ago       Up 29 seconds       8080/tcp            mongo-client-api
8f3e19c3b631        mongo                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   27017/tcp           mongocontainer
```

My configuraion in my spring boot app is:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongocontainer:27017/test
```

When spring boot container start, it can't connect to mongo db:

```
2020-04-14 08:15:20.525  INFO 1 --- [           main] p.c.e.m.MongoClientApiApplication        : Starting MongoClientApiApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 213526cf2bd4 with PID 1 (/opt/app.jar started by root in /opt)
2020-04-14 08:15:20.536  INFO 1 --- [           main] p.c.e.m.MongoClientApiApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-14 08:15:21.923  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-14 08:15:22.036  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 105ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2020-04-14 08:15:23.015  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-14 08:15:23.033  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-14 08:15:23.035  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-14 08:15:23.156  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-14 08:15:23.157  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2436 ms
2020-04-14 08:15:23.523  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2020-04-14 08:15:23.617  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Why I can't connect these two containers?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**

I add logs from mongo container:

```
2020-04-14T08:14:30.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=8f3e19c3b631
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.5
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 2261279b51ea13df08ae708ff278f0679c59dc32
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-04-14T08:14:30.467+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "*" } }
2020-04-14T08:14:30.468+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2020-04-14T08:14:30.468+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-04-14T08:14:30.468+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2020-04-14T08:14:30.468+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=556M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2020-04-14T08:14:31.134+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1586852071:134123][1:0x7f8c32783b00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
2020-04-14T08:14:31.677+0000 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2020-04-14T08:14:31.697+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
2020-04-14T08:14:31.703+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-04-14T08:14:31.703+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-04-14T08:14:31.704+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-04-14T08:14:31.704+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-04-14T08:14:31.705+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: b82de6d0-72bb-4387-b456-79827a0bc50c and options: { uuid: UUID("b82de6d0-72bb-4387-b456-79827a0bc50c") }
2020-04-14T08:14:31.742+0000 I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns admin.system.version
2020-04-14T08:14:31.743+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-04-14T08:14:31.743+0000 I  COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.2
2020-04-14T08:14:31.744+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-04-14T08:14:31.744+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
2020-04-14T08:14:31.745+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-04-14T08:14:31.745+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: 51de49e8-f4fc-4873-a5ed-ddc3ecedbec4 and options: { capped: true, size: 10485760 }
2020-04-14T08:14:31.782+0000 I  INDEX    [initandlisten] index build: done building index _id_ on ns local.startup_log
2020-04-14T08:14:31.786+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-04-14T08:14:31.794+0000 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2020-04-14T08:14:31.801+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-04-14T08:14:31.802+0000 I  STORAGE  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] createCollection: config.system.sessions with provided UUID: 4e27e6b9-10d2-457c-ac54-b34d9bae09c9 and options: { uuid: UUID("4e27e6b9-10d2-457c-ac54-b34d9bae09c9") }
2020-04-14T08:14:31.802+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2020-04-14T08:14:31.802+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 0.0.0.0
2020-04-14T08:14:31.802+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
2020-04-14T08:14:31.815+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: done building index _id_ on ns config.system.sessions
2020-04-14T08:14:31.825+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: starting on config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 } using method: Hybrid
2020-04-14T08:14:31.825+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build may temporarily use up to 200 megabytes of RAM
2020-04-14T08:14:31.825+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: collection scan done. scanned 0 total records in 0 seconds
2020-04-14T08:14:31.827+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: inserted 0 keys from external sorter into index in 0 seconds
2020-04-14T08:14:31.828+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: done building index lsidTTLIndex on ns config.system.sessions
2020-04-14T08:14:31.830+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-04-14T08:14:32.003+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
```

Comment: Can you also post the logs from the mongo container?

Comment: @als I've updated question with logs from mongo container

Comment: Are you able to ping to mongo container from mongoclient container using hostname?
Run the following command from mongo-client-api container and paste the output  - `ping -c 2 mongocontainer`

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal I had to install iputils-ping package before but the got ip neither works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve my problem.

I didn't notice that when spring boot container run, it tries to connect to localhost when it should connect to host mongocontainer. It is due to Spring Dat Mongo connects to localhost by default. So, I have to create a custom configuration to mongo database:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongocontainer:27017/test
```

Config class:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String uri;

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(new ConnectionString(this.uri)));
    }
}
```

And exclude some autoconfiguration classes:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MongoClientApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MongoClientApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then I again run my  mongo and spring boot container:

`docker run --network=springmongo --name=mongocontainer mongo` (I was not necessary specify ports)

Before run spring boot container, I had to create the image again for update my spring boot app with last changes (very important):

```
docker build -t mongo-client-api .
```

Then run spring boot container:

```
docker run --network=springmongo -p 8080:8080 --rm --name=mongo-client-api mongo-client-api
```

Now, for getting the IP of my spring boot app I run this command:

`minikube ip` (I'm using minikube)

As additional data: when I use `host.docker.internal` instead of `mongocontainer` I never can connect to my mongo container. I ran ping from spring boot container to `host.docker.internal` but I neither could connect

Answer (score 0):

you are using the name of the Docker container (`mongocontainer`) as hostname in the SpringBoot app.

Use instead `host.docker.internal` which resolves to the host internal IP. Port number is fine as this is the one exposed by the Mongo container.

Comment: I replaced `mongocontainer` by `host.docker.internal` but I get the same error yet.

Comment: Uhm, weird, just noticed your docker run should expose the port ie `docker run -p 27017:27017`

Comment: I've include parameters related to ports when I run mongo container but I continue getting the same error. It happens both with `host.docker.internal` variable and direct IP